How to retain original Entity IDs when migrating Paragraphs
We're migrating D7 to D10 Paragraphs and the Paragraph IDs are not being retained. It is setting new, sequential ID's when importing and we need the original ID's retained to use for mapping to the nodes.
The current Paragraph YML looks like this:
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: { }
id: d7_paragraph_diagnosis
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 7'
migration_group: migrate_drupal_7
label: Diagnosis Migrate
source:
  plugin: d7_paragraphs_item
  bundle: diagnosis
destination:
  plugin: 'entity_reference_revisions:paragraph'
  default_bundle: diagnosis
process:
  id: item_id # I thought this mapping would retain the ID, but it doesn't
  revision_id: revision_id
  field_text: field_text
  field_link:
    plugin: field_link
    uri_scheme: 'https://'
    source: field_link     

We're using "drush migrate-import d7_paragraphs:diagnosis" to import.
NOTE: It seemed to work at first then at some point stopped working. Even after restoring to a backup from yesterday and making sure all of the migration tables were empty. Either I was mistaken that the ID's seemed to map/import correctly or it stopped working for some unknown reason.
EDIT:
Overview: 5 Paragraph types. 4 contain a text field and a link field. The last Paragraph type (table_row) contains 4 Paragraph references (to the previous 4 Paragraph types). See screenshot examples.


After restoring the DB and rolling back all migrations I started over and ran:
drush mim d7_paragraphs_type (success 5 of 5)
drush mim d7_paragraphs:diagnosis (success 142 of 142)
drush mim d7_paragraphs:icd10_left (success 142 of 142)
drush mim d7_paragraphs:icd10_right (success 142 of 142)
drush mim d7_paragraphs:procedure_cpt (success 142 of 142)
drush mim d7_paragraphs:table_row (success 142 of 142)

I've created a Paragraphs View to reviewing the entities and it appears that that data exists, but with new sequential ID's.  So, everything looks okay so far but when I run the mim paragraph_revisions_x it fails with an error:

QUESTIONS:
1 - Any idea why the revisions is failing saying the previous (successful) migration is failing?
2 - Are the revisions required, or could I possibly skip this step?
3 - If the revisions are not needed then would I need to create a custom migration to populate the nodes (basic_page) fields with the Paragraph references?

The usual way to handle this is to use a migration lookup when you migrate the nodes. That way, you don't need to worry about the actual ID in D10.

I forgot to say, it's also safer, in that you don't have to worry about possible collisions.

First, some theory.
In general, preserving IDs is considered a bad practice, because migrations can be rolled back, and the next migration import will have different (higher) IDs.
Furthermore, you may add some manual content in between of migrations being executed, and this content will consume some IDs which you might have in your migration, and of course you won't be able to use those IDs.
FYI: migrate module stores mappings of SRC_ID:DEST_ID and it has tools (like migrate_lookup, entity_lookup) to get you the IDs you need later.
You should be able to rollback/import migrations more than 1 time and if you have your dependencies set properly, you should not see any differences, although the IDs will be different (higher) for each mim executed.
Second, some speculations (pardon if I am wrong)
Considering that you say it was working, but it does not now, I assume you did not roll back your migrations, but you did a manual cleanup of the tables. If what I say is true: you should never do this.
Always use drush mim/drush mr.
If your migration (mim) failed with an exception, do drush mrs (reset) then drush mr (rollback). Always check migration status with drush ms so you see the current status.
How to check this assumption: check the tables and drush ms. If tables are empty but drush ms reports migrations, then you have mapping tables filled with nonexistent data.
What to do if what I say is true: rollback your migrations. (drush mrs && drush mr)
Migrating paragraphs is (a) migrating the paragraph entities (b) migrating the data for the nodes (or other entities) fields which reference the paragraphs.
First you should make sure that paragraphs data is migrated (e.g. you can see the paragraphs data with DB UI, but when you open your nodes, the fields show nothing, which is fine.
You should not do anything with keys (id and revision_id) when doing migrations. IDs will be created automatically (and they will be new i.e. they won't match the original). After that, if you need to reference this ID, you should use migrate_lookup.
In general, you should do:

d7_paragraph_types
d7_paragraphs
d7_paragraphs_revisions (See modules/contrib/paragraphs/migrations/**).

At this point you should have paragraphs data, but the nodes won't have references to those paragraphs (i.e. you see data with DB UI like Phpmyadmin, but when you open the content/node, you don't see any paragraphs there).
After you make sure for your node fields you should use migrate field with the "paragraphs" @MigrateField (see  modules/contrib/paragraphs/src/Plugin/migrate/field/Paragraphs.php).
At this moment you should use migrate_lookup to get an actual (new) ID value for your DEST paragraph based on the old value of the field in SRC table.
If what I say does not help, please provide additional info:
(a) What does drush ms report at the beginning for d7_paragraph_types, d7_paragraphs, d7_paragraphs_revisions and your nodes/entities migrations? (like migrated 0/834)
(b) Do you have data in destination tables: paragraphs_item, paragraphs_item_field_data, paragraphs_item_revision, paragraphs_item_revision_field_data, paragraphs_revision__[FIELDNAME]?
(c) I assume you did not do node migrations (yet) or if you did, what yaml do you have for the node?

Thank you so much, Alex, for your thorough assistance on this. I've updated my original post with more info and screenshots after resetting everything and starting over with your suggestions. The Paragraph's data is in the DB and verified using a View to show the Paragraphs rendered entities. However, the import of _paragraphs_revisions is failing.  In short, I think I'm stuck on the next/final step of mapping the Paragraphs to the nodes.

I think I got it working! I ended up having to use the --force flag on the revision and node imports, but it worked and the paragraphs and node references all seem intact. Thank you for your help.
